# Newly added category attribute not saving in magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2

I followed this tutorial to add an attribute to my category :

> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-category-attributes-programmatically/

This is my installdata.php

```
<?php
namespace XX\XX\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'categ_front_label',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Label for category',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

and here is my category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="categ_front_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Label For Category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The new field is appearing on the back-end when i click a category but when i hit save it goes back to being a blank field, can anyone help?

Comment: I'd follow this guide it worked for myself - http://milandev.me/magento-2-how-to-add-extra-category-description-in-the-product-listing-page/ - If it still doesn't show then re-install the module via SSH ~ setup:upgrade

Comment: @A.Lal i got The attribute with a "label_for_fornt_category" attributeCode doesn't exist. Verify the attribute and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Please Follow this Code :-

> > app/code/vendor/module_name/Setup/InstallData.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Category\Description\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

        private $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        public function install(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context
        )
        {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'category_description',
                [
                    'type'         => 'varchar',
                    'label'        => 'Category Description',
                    'input'        => 'text',
                    'sort_order'   => 100,
                    'source'       => '',
                    'global'       => 1,
                    'visible'      => true,
                    'required'     => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default'      => null,
                    'group'        => '',
                    'backend'      => ''
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Step 2:- And add the last Code below path :-

> app/code/vendor/module_name/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_from.php

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="general">
            <field name="category_description">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Category Description</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And Finally Run the ,
***php bin/magento s:up***
***php bin/magento c:f***

Hope it help

Thanks.

Comment: Hello , @gazzz it is working or not ??